# SharePoint deleted my phone number authentication

Tags: authentication, sharepoint, microsoft365

I receive push messages for Microsoft account sing-on. I deleted my phone authentication from SharePoint and I am unable to sign-in now. I am the admin for the microsoft365, SharePoint.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may get help here:[Common problems with two-factor verification and your work or school account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/user-help/multi-factor-authentication-end-user-troubleshoot)

Otherwise, you may have to contact official technical support for o365:[Ways to contact support for business products - Admin Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/contact-support-for-business-products?view=o365-worldwide)